# Mongo C# - Update behavior, creating dummy record when no match

Tags: c#, mongodb

With MongoDB, when I do an update that doesn't match any documents, the update returns that it didn't update any documents, but yet a document gets created

Here's the code:

```
    public class MyObject
    {
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Client      = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var Database    = Client.GetDatabase("testdatabase");
        var Driver      = Database.GetCollection<MyObject>("testcollection");
        Driver.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<MyObject>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _._id));

        var C1 = Driver.Count(_ => true);
        // c1 == 0 since the db is empty

        var A1 = Driver.UpdateMany(_ => false, Builders<MyObject>.Update.Set(_ => _.X, 1), new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});
        //A1.MatchedCount == 0
        //A1.ModifiedCount == 0;
        //A1.Upsertdld = (some id)

        var C2 = Driver.Count(_ => true);
        // c2 == 1 because a dummy document was created due to the upsert flag

        var A2 = Driver.UpdateMany(_ => true, Builders<MyObject>.Update.Set(_ => _.X, 3), new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});
        //A2.MatchedCount == 1
        //A2.ModifiedCount == 1;
        //A2.Upsertdld = null;

        var C3 = Driver.Count(_ => true);
        // c3 == 1 since no new dummy documents were created as there was a match

    }
```

It looks like the *Upsert* flag is the culprit, but I don't understand why it creates a document out of thin air since there is nothing to update.
(On the second call, it has a match and will not create a dummy.)

Comment: Upsert behaviour is to insert a document when there is no match and update the document when there is match. Seems like that's what is happening. were you expecting something else ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: I expected it to behave a bit differently: I have strings as _id (they're essentially microsoft formatted guids) and it's part of the MyObject type. But when update does upsert an empty document, it will create a record with ObjectId as type for _id; then all subsequent calls will fail since the record can't be deserialized into the type I created.

Comment: would there be a way to force the creation of the record where _id would essentially be default(typeof(_id))? in this case default(string)?

Comment: You can try including the `_id` as part of query condition so upserted entry gets created with the specified id or other option will be to separate insert from update, which means upsert flag is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `IsUpsert = true` you call the MongoDB C# Driver to find for at least one document to update or insert a new document.
When your collection is empty an insert command will execute instead; like this:

```
//var A1 = Driver.UpdateMany(_ => false, Builders<MyObject>.Update.Set(_ => _.X, 1), new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});

var A1 = Driver.InsertOne(new MyObject { X = 1 });
```

So as documented:

> If the document does not specify an `_id` field, then MongoDB will add the `_id` field and assign a unique `ObjectId` for the document before inserting. Most drivers create an `ObjectId` and insert the `_id` field, but the mongod will create and populate the `_id` if the driver or application does not.

And in newer versions of C# MongoDB Drivers you can use `Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Empty` instead of `_ => true` as recommended.